# How do I bypass the File Conversion dialog when opening a text file from Word using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

My applescript needs to open about a hundred text files in Microsoft Word. Every time it opens a file, Word pops up a "File Conversion" dialog, asking me to specify the file encoding. The files only use ascii characters so any standard encoding will work but I don't see a way to specify the conversion in the script. My script has code like this:

```
repeat with i from 4 to 100
    set docName to prefix & i & ".txt"
    open docName file converter open format encoded text
    ... rest of operation
end repeat
```

I've tried `open docName` and `open docName file converter open format encoded text` but neither works. I can't sit and wait for it each time it opens a file, it takes too long to process the files. Is there a quick way past this dialog?

Comment: You need to include the version of Word in your question. Do you have `Confirm conversion at Open` enabled in Preferences > General?

Comment: @Mockman Good point. I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.73. Retail License 2019.
I don't have `Confirm file format conversion at Open` checked, but that's about file format, and the dialog I'm getting is about the character encoding.

Comment: I see your point. That's a strange dialogue. It isn't in applescript's list of dialogues. Note that I'm using Word 2011 (v14) which doesn't seem to have some of the encoding features that later versions have. You might check to see if word's AS dictionary for your version includes the dialogue. If it does, you might at least be able to automate your choice. Also, you could use UI scripting to click on the OK button each time through the loop.

Comment: My version doesn't have it either. And I have no idea how to use the script to click on the OK button.

Comment: With Word being the active app, put `key code 36` inside a system events tell block. Key code 36 simulates pressing the 'return' key. You may have to add a delay in the process to give time to get the dialogue on screen.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work. It didn't process my delay command or my "tell System events" commands until after I had closed the troublesome File Conversion dialog.